yamldotnet read generic file C#
so I'm trying to read yaml files and store them in json in a database, so I can do some bulk querying of them.  Trouble is - I can't seem to be able to make a generic function that reads yaml files.   I started with:
    public static string ToJson(string yaml)
    {
        var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().Build();
        var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize<object>(yaml);
        return Json.Serialize(yamlObject);
    }

but am getting things like "unresolved tag !master".    Now - this a whole bag of yaml files of different types from different sources - they could be using anything...
I tried this:
    public static string ToJson(string yaml)
    {
        var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().IgnoreUnmatchedProperties()
            .WithNodeDeserializer(inner => new IgnoreUnknownTagsDeserializer(inner),
                s => s.InsteadOf<ObjectNodeDeserializer>()).Build();
        var yamlObject = deserializer.Deserialize<object>(yaml);
        return Json.Serialize(yamlObject);
    }

with my own function to look for a tag name starting with ! - but my function doesn't get called.
So currently I'm writing my own deserialization library from a base level parsing library - but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.    Surely it's possible to write a generic function that takes any yaml and turns it into json??   I know people can build custom tags and they can do things, but it's very unlikely I'll be querying them anyway - I just want to do anything with them so I can get a serialization of the rest of the yaml?

actually - got it bascially working with a hack - I am using regex to replace @"!([\w\d]+) with Custom$1 - and I can now load documents!!!      but I'd still be interested in a "real" solution

Sample yaml file?
